How can I replace my bathroom sink water supply valve?
I have a leaking valve stem & tightening screw didn't help. What type of valve is this & can I remove it without heat in order to replace it
with a new one?


Where exactly is it leaking?  Replacement may not be needed. You may be tightening the wrong part.

If those are a standard valve, you can get repair kits that replace all the seals and the...guts, whatever you call the rotating part inside.

Likely, you can replace the valve packing and/or washer.

Look at a diagram of a shutoff valve, such as at Family Handyman. From your excellent photo, that packing is inside the packing nut, in the area outlined, below. It appears the packing material has been repaired with white Teflon tape, sticking out top and bottom.



Shut the main water supply.
Drain lines a bit (e.g., flush toilets until they no longer work).
Place a basin underneath valve to catch water.
Unscrew the handle, if feasible, to give more room to work.
Grab the packing nut with a strap wrench or other tool which would protect finish and turn counter-clockwise to remove the nut.
Replace the packing material. In some cases, graphite-coated string was originally used, in others, a rubber washer. Replacements can be found at most hardware stores for low cost.
Reassemble.
Turn on main valve and check for leaks.


The tape appears to be a tail from the sink supply connection, not the valve innards.

Maybe fix it
Are you sure it's the stem that is leaking and sure you tightened it? Tape should not be used on the compression fitting for the hose. The leak might be there. Remove that tape and replace the hose. A compression fitting does not rely on the threads for its seal, and the tape might be preventing it from making.
If it is the stem, you said you tightened the screw but the screw in the picture only holds the handle on. You need to tighten the nut behind the handle.
Or maybe replace it
You have plenty of pipe sticking out of the wall, and it looks like a fairly new supply hose. I suggest you just replace that valve. Extremely easy and cheap.
Carefully unscrew the hose without damaging it.  Cut the pipe just behind the valve with a hacksaw or a pipe cutter.  Buy and install a SharkBite 1/2x3/8 compression 90 degree supply valve..   Throw out the compression olive and nut that come with the valve and screw your hose on. Done.
The valve is about 10 bucks, and you'll need about 10 bucks worth of a new tools including a shark bite measuring/deburring tool. Watch some tutorials on YouTube.  Read the instructions. It's easy to get this wrong, but much easier to get it right with zero experience than any other kind of valve if you follow the instructions carefully.

Wow. Thank you, so much!!! I guess I'm off to store again, lol. I truly appreciate 0that you took your time to impart your wisdom with me!! Ty!
